# Binding and Searching Large DataTable

Tags: wpf, serialization, datatable

I have implemented Auto Complete drop down list in WPF

It is giving issues when a large data (say over 30 MB) is bind to it

What is the best approach to work on large data (Operations like Searching)

Is it possible to serialize 30 MB data and as User type in Autocomplete Drop Down List, Search

in to serialized data and attach resulting data to Drop Down List and show it to the User

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should put time-consuming operations in BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler not setting controls properties as above. if you want to set a property of control which have been created in another thread in BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler then you should use Control.Invoke method to set properties asynchronously. nevertherless following code is better solution:

```
   toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Loading ... ";


enter code here` backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

enter code here`backgroundWorker1_DoWork(/*arguments*/)
{
// getting data from database and fill dataset
}

backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(/*arguments*/)
{
            dt_kh = ds.Tables[0];

            cboMaKH.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cboMaKH.DisplayMember = "MaKH";
            cboMaKH.ValueMember = "MaKH";


            cboTenCty.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cboTenCty.DisplayMember = "TenCty";
            cboTenCty.ValueMember = "TenCty";

            cboMaKH.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; 
            cboMaKH.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            cboMaKH.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            cboTenCty.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            cboTenCty.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            cboTenCty.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

            txtTenKH.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "TenKH");
            txtDiaChi.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "Diachicty");
            txtDienThoai.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "DienThoaiCty");
            txtTaiKhoan.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "TaiKhoanCty");
            txtVIMST.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "MSTCty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your autocomplete textbox using `ICollectionView.Filter` to search values?

If yes then it is bound to be slow for large data sets being synchronous.

Use PLINQ to your advantage.

When a user types a text in the textbox, perform the PLINQ query to entries that start with \ contain the text that is typed, and then rebind the itemssource after the PLINQ query returns.

If you cant use PLINQ or dont have .Net 4.0, then perform the simple LINQ search on a different thread and rebind over the `Dispatcher` of the autocomplete box.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Comment. But if i am fetching around 30 mb data in my application, application memory will increase. so is it feasible to fetch all the data on client?

Comment: Yes why not? It is a desktop application correct? You have 4GB virtual memory atleast for a 32 bit system.